# portType binding wsdl parsing error

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have problem with creating wsdl file for soap service. I have declarated in wsdl file

```
<portType name="RegistrationService">
    <operation name="registration">
        <input message="tns:registration"/>
        <output message="tns:registrationResponse"/>
        <fault message="tns:ServerException" name="ServerException" />
        <fault message="tns:ValidationException" name="ValidationException" />
        <fault message="tns:DenialOfServiceException" name="DenialOfServiceException" />
    </operation>
</portType>
```

And then try to use it like this

```
    <binding name="RegistrationBinding" type="tns:RegistrationService">
</binding>
```

but validator throws me

```
Could not find the portType definition for 'tns:RegistrationService' in the binding'RegistrationBinding'.
```

I can't get what's wrong with it, because i'm using and call it correctly.

Comment: Check if the namespaces are correct please or try with removing the tns namespace like : <binding name="RegistrationBinding" type="RegistrationService">

Comment: thanks, your answers helped. there were problem with declaration the types. soon, i'll post correct answer.

Comment: Hey, 3 years later but I have the same errors, can you post the answer ? Thx